# python __getattr__ help

Tags: python, python-datamodel, getattr

Reading a Book, i came across this code...

```
# module person.py

class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, job=None, pay=0):
        self.name = name
        self.job  = job
        self.pay  = pay

    def lastName(self):
        return self.name.split()[-1]

    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        self.pay = int(self.pay *(1 + percent))

    def __str__(self):
        return "[Person: %s, %s]" % (self.name,self.pay)

class Manager():
    def __init__(self, name, pay):
        self.person = Person(name, "mgr", pay)

    def giveRaise(self, percent, bonus=.10):
        self.person.giveRaise(percent + bonus)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.person, attr)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.person)
```

It does what I want it to do, but i do not understand the `__getattr__` function in the `Manager` class. I know that it Delegates all other attributes from `Person` class. but I do not understand the way it works. for example why from `Person` class? as I do not explicitly tell it to. person(module is different than Person(class)

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Mmh either the code is old or bad or I don't see the trick behind it. But I would just let the `Manager` class inherit from `Person`. But I don't really understand your question. You say you know what `getattr` is doing. As for why it delegates to `self.person`: I didn't write this code so I can only assume that a `Manager` is a `Person`. In the constructor a new `Person` is created.

Comment: It's really old code: it doesn't subclass from `object`, so they're old-style classes.  Oh, and it's broken: `Person.lastName` doesn't return the right answer for someone with the surname "de la Garza".

Comment: What book are you reading? This looks badly written imho...

Comment: i am reading Learning Python from O Reilly. i know it is the "bad" code......he just wants to show the getattr... In the right code, he inherited really well from the Person Class

Answer (score 2):

1. In your `__init__` you instantiate a `Person` object which gets assigned to self.person.
2. You then override attribute lookups on the Manager instance (by implementing `__getattr__` for this class) and redirect these attributes to be looked up on the self.person variable instead (which is the `Person` object from 1 in this particular case).

Like Felix Kling mentioned in the comments, it would make more sense to make `Manager` inherit from `Person`.  In the current code above, it looks like the manager *has* a person while it's more logical to think that the manager *is* a person.

You could do something like this:

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name, job=None, pay=0):
        self.name = name
        self.job = job
        self.pay = pay

    def give_raise(self, percent):
        self.pay = int(self.pay *(1 + percent))

    def __str__(self):
        return "[Person: %s, %s]" % (self.name, self.pay)

class Manager(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, pay):
        super(Manager, self).__init__(name, "mgr", pay)

    def give_raise(self, percent, bonus=.10):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * (1 + (percent + bonus)))

# example usage
John = Person("John", "programmer", 1000)
Dave = Manager("Dave", 2000)
print John, Dave
John.give_raise(.20)
Dave.give_raise(.20)
print John, Dave
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do tell it explicitly - not by naming the class, but by providing an instance of that class.

In the `init` method, you bind `self.person` to an instance of `Person`.  Now, every `Manager` instance will have this data member.

In `__getattr__`, you are delegating to the `getattr` builtin with `self.person` as the first argument.  Regardless of the type of `self.person`, it will look for a member with the given name.

Comment: If I create a Manager object: m=Manager("Fred",1200), why doesn't m.person end up getting m.person.person?

Answer (score 0):

Beside reading a Book, you might want to consult [*The Book*](http://docs.python.org/index.html) where you could have found a pretty clear explanation of how [`__getattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattr__#object.__getattr__) methods work.

In a nutshell, it gets called when there are no attributes of the specified name attached to the object it's being applied to, and also not to the object class or any of it's superclasses. In other words, it called when all else fails.

In the code in your example, the implementation of `__getattr_()` effectively redirects the search for the named attribute onto the `self.person` object, which is an instance of the `Person` class.

It also important to understand that `__getattr_()` is the first step in accessing both the data and the methods associated with any object.